# C++ initialization strange behavior

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

```
typedef struct node {
    
    int val;
    int val2;
    
    node(int a, int b) : val(a), val2(b) {}
    node(int val) = delete;
}node;

int main()
{
    node a = {3};
    cout << a.val << " " << a.val2 << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

---

The above code gives compile error showing that use of deleted function `node::node(int)`.

However, when I remove `node(int a, int b) : a(val), b(val2) {}`, this code compiles without a problem. How would this happen?

Comment: IDK if it'll fix the issue but you probably meant to write `node(int a, int b) : val(a), val2(b) {}` instead.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, I have edited it. but my question is still valid.

Comment: Congratulations, you learned that C++ is thorny. That's a rite of passage.

Answer (score 11):

Before C++20 explicitly deleted constructors are allowed for [aggregate type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). If you remove `node(int a, int b)` and leave `node(int val) = delete;` only, `node` is considered as aggregate and `node a = {3};` performs aggregate initialization, constructors won't be used, as the effect `a.val` is initialized as `3` and `a.val2` is initialized as `0` directly.

> no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11) (until C++17)
>
> no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++17) (until C++20)

C++20 has fixed this behavior. `node a = {3};` performs [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), the deleted constructor will be used and the code is ill-formed.

> no user-declared or inherited constructors (since C++20)

BTW: The usage of `typedef` in the definition of `node` is superfluous, you can just write it as `struct node { ... };`.

Comment: @Const At least C++20 made it a little better..

Comment: "Better" that we say in every language standard updates !

Comment: Good thing arrays work like a charm then... o wait...